# SCP not working with a .ppk key

Tags: ssh, scp

so I need to connect to a remote server. Remote server is running Debian, I am on Ubuntu Lucid -- and a noob in SSH.

I need a public key to connect to the remote server. The key has been created as a PuTTY Pageant File (.ppk). I used `putty-tools` to convert the .ppk key to Linux files (namely, *id_rsa* and *id_rsa.pub*). SSH works okay, but when I try to SCP a file terminal says :

```
# scp -P 52 /path/to/local/file user@host.com:/path/to/remote/file

Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Also, it's not working using SFTP with FileZilla:

```
Command:    Trust new Hostkey: Once
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

How come it's working with SSH and not SCP? Thanks!

Edit: it's working now! Not really sure why... How is that passphrase system working with SSH? Does it keep the passphrase in th terminal's memory? This time I've connected to SSH in one terminal tab. I was prompted my passphrase, entered it and got in. Then on another terminal tab, I tried to scp a file and I've been asked the passphrase and it worked!....

Comment: please provide more information. :) try and connect and add verbose tak.

Comment: Yes, please run `scp` with the `-v` option added at the start.  And tell us how you are running the `ssh` that works.

Comment: it works now! not sure why but it does! How should I treat the question now? should i mark it solved?

Answer (score 2):

Is `id_rsa` in `~/.ssh`? This is where `ssh` and `scp` looks for the private keys.

Also if your using a private key you shouldn't be prompted for a password, this would suggests that it is not being used, and also that it is not required.

I'm also confused as to why your using putty if both systems are Linux.

Comment: Linux has built in SSH support: you can run `ssh user@host` and it will work. You don't need PuTTY to use SSH on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice of Mikel (thanks!) I ran with the -v option and received a stinging reminder that I was trying to run scp as root. Silly me, I had set up all the shared key credentials in the home directory of the non-root user.

After severely chastising myself, then going to /root/.ssh and copying three files from /home//.ssh, my efforts were met with success.

JBR